# Use function $(this) and next() etc in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one"><input type="text"></td><td class="two"><input type="text" value="12"></td><td class="three"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one"><input type="text"></td><td class="two"><input type="text" value="22"></td><td class="three"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one"><input type="text"></td><td class="two"><input type="text" value="14"></td><td class="three"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(".one input").change(function(){
   ???
})
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/34Vtk/

If i fill value to first column (`.one`) then this value should be multiplied by `.two input.val()` and result should show in `.three.input.val()` .

I can make this with ID, but i can't use function `$(this)` and `next()` :( These input is a lot and  i must use for this `$(this)` and `next()`, not ID.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both `$(this)` and the parent `tr` element as a context.

Try this:

```
$(".one input, .two input").change(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $one = $(".one input", $row);
    var $two = $(".two input", $row);

    var val1 = $one.val();
    var val2 = $two.val();
    var val3 = val1 * val2;

    $(".three input", $row).val(val3);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/34Vtk/5/)

You will most likely also need to attach this to the `.two input` as well so that the figure gets updated when that element changes too, and also some form of validation to ensure valid numbers are entered.

This code can be shortened, I've just made it a bit more verbose to make it as clear as possible what's happening.

Comment: thanks. and how can i show always result as FLOAT? http://jsfiddle.net/34Vtk/6/ now if value = 11.00 then this show my only 22 instead of 22.00